curl http2 error on a particular url but works on other similar pdf url
I have done a simple curl call, for one website it works and for another it does not. When opened in chrome both have similar PDF output renderred.
Command that works
curl -v https://www.bseindia.com/bseplus/AnnualReport/543258/74183543258.pdf -o bse_file.pdf

Command that does not work
curl  -v https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/equities/IPO_RHP_UNICOMM.pdf -o nse_file.pdf

Error : curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)
curl version
curl --version
curl 8.4.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0) libcurl/8.4.0 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/3.3.6 zlib/1.2.12 nghttp2/1.58.0

Verbose curl trace for error
$ curl  -v https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/equities/IPO_RHP_UNICOMM.pdf -o nse_file.pdf
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 23.46.207.147:443...
* Connected to nsearchives.nseindia.com (23.46.207.147) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [329 bytes data]
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
{ [29 bytes data]
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [4274 bytes data]
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [80 bytes data]
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [36 bytes data]
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [36 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=IN; ST=Maharashtra; L=Mumbai; O=National Stock Exchange of India Ltd; CN=www.nseindia.com
*  start date: Aug 21 00:00:00 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 28 23:59:59 2025 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "nsearchives.nseindia.com" matched cert's "nsearchives.nseindia.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/2
* [HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/equities/IPO_RHP_UNICOMM.pdf
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:method: GET]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: nsearchives.nseindia.com]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /content/equities/IPO_RHP_UNICOMM.pdf]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [user-agent: curl/8.4.0]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept: */*]
> GET /content/equities/IPO_RHP_UNICOMM.pdf HTTP/2
> Host: nsearchives.nseindia.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host nsearchives.nseindia.com left intact
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

Alternatives tried:
From this answer I tried using --http1.1 with curl to downgrade the protocol. With this the download begins but goes on and on, never ends.
curl -v --http1.1  https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/equities/IPO_RHP_UNICOMM.pdf -o curl_file.pdf


All I can do is confirm similar behavior in the US. Browser download works, similar message from curl : `HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

stopped the pause stream!
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Connection #0 to host nsearchives.nseindia.com left intact
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2), It seems like it is on the nseindia.com side. Maybe try other cmd-line tools?wget` and a few others? Good luck.


See last comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78924767/php-cant-read-rss-feed-using-curl#comment139154886_78924767 for a likely explanation.

Hello @Nitiraj, I am experiencing the same kind of issues on curl side but with language R and library Shiny (see question here). I have a feeling that the file size might be an explanation. Is 74183543258.pdf smaller in size than IPO_RHP_UNICOMM.pdf?

See workaround here: try to "find a way to store content even if there are some issues with closing that connection"

The likely reason curl cannot complete a successful request to that second website is because it detects when a request is not coming from a browser and blocks it.
A solution is available from //https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate.  It provides curl executables that imitate the four major browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Microsoft Edge.  For example, this will fetch that PDF file:
curl_chrome110 https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/equities/IPO_RHP_UNICOMM.pdf -o nse_file.pdf

