PHP Can't Read RSS Feed Using Curl
I've been using a PHP program running in a shell to read a Washington Post RSS feed.  It's been working fine for over a year, but it stopped working on August 2, 2024.  Here is a very simple example program:
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.washingtonpost.com/arcio/rss/');

$result = curl_exec($curl);

if ($result === false) {
  print "Error: " . curl_error($curl) . "\n";
} else {
  print "$result\n";
}

?>

It used to return XML text like this:
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Washington Post</title> 
    <description>Washington Post News Feed</description>
    etc etc etc

But now it returns this error:

HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

I have tried several things, such as setting CURLOPT_REFERER and CURLOPT_USERAGENT to what a browser's values would be, but that didn't help.  I also tried setting CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION to CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, and while that made the error message go away, the attempted curl_get_contents() call times out, even when the timeout is set to 60 seconds.
I then modified the program slightly, loaded it onto a local development website, ran it from a browser window, and received the HTTP/2 stream 1... message again, so it isn't running from outside a browser that is the problem.
The XML file I'm trying to access is still there.  I know this because entering its URL into a browser's address box causes the page of XML text to be displayed in the browser's window.
file_get_contents() didn't work either.
Any advice?

Please post the relevant code of curl_get_contents

curl_get_contents isn't a built-in or documented PHP function, so you'll need to show us the code of that function so we can understand exactly what it's doing. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

I tried curl -o rss.xml https://www.washingtonpost.com/arcio/rss/ on the Windows command line. It worked but only after 9 seconds. There's something weird with the server.

Someone else reporting the same issue (on a different site) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78921869/curl-http2-error-on-a-particular-url-but-works-on-other-similar-pdf-url

washingtonpost.com is behind Akami, and has a weird JavaScript-based protection scheme, meaning content is always available until JS says otherwise. My guess is that they are using Akami to block script-based access in an attempt to thwart content scraping which could more easily bypass this. You might be able to get around this by sending the exact headers that a client sends, in the exact order, and/or sending requests from what they consider to be the IP address of a "regular user".

The question was closed because I had poorly constructed it.  I edited the question and made the requested improvements.  Dharman edited my edit to remove my meta comment that the question had been edited, but the question remains closed.  Please let me know what additional improvements I can make that would allow the question to be reopened.  Thanks.

Could someone please describe what I need to do to get this question reopened?

@Dharman Sorry for the alert, but I'm seeking help to reopen this question, and you were the last person to edit the question.

@percy If the normal review process doesn't handle it, you can ask for help on Meta to improve the question so that it can be reopened. I am not going to vote to reopen it.

I can't see that you have added this to the review. Edit the post to clarify the closure reason and submit for review.

@Dharman Apologiies again, but I believe I already followed your suggestion to "clarify the closure reason and submit for review" 13 days ago.  In the box at the top it says, "This post was edited and submitted for review 13 days ago."  If the question still has problems it would be very helpful to me if someone could tell me what they are.  I'm not looking for votes to reopen - I didn't even know a voting process existed.

If that's what you are looking for then Meta is the place where you can ask for it.

Thank you to whoever and however this was finally reopened.

I recently found the answer to my own question.  The Washington Post, and doubtless many other websites, uses software that can detect whether requests are from a browser or from something else.  This webpage at ScrapFly describes the techniques used by Akamai, the package used by the Washington Post, to detect non-browser attempts to access: Akamai Detection Techniques
While the Washington Post does hinder scraping of their webpages (for instance, by introducing a 10 second delay before responding to the request), they do allow it.  It was their own RSS feeds (for example, https://www.washingtonpost.com/arcio/rss/) that they began blocking by non-browsers on August 2, 2024.  Browsers could still access these feeds, but they're in XML format with links appearing as plain text, not very useful when displayed on a browser page, and requiring additional steps to process into a useful form.
The information supplied by the ScrapFly website is sufficient for brewing your own solutions, but there's a readymade alternative available with curl_impersonate at https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate.  It can mimic the behavior of the four major browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Microsoft Edge.
I needed a PHP solution and so additionally used kelvinzer0/curl-impersonate-php, which performs the necessary setup and invokes the curl_impersonate executables.
